# Android SIM operator and network operator equivalent in iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, objective-c, sms

In Android you can get the **SIM operator** and **network operator** codes easily via [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) using [getSimOperator()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimOperator%28%29) and [getNetworkOperator()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperator%28%29). Each of this methods return the MCC+MNC string. So you get one MCC+MNC string for the SIM operator and another MCC+MNC string for the current network operator.

My understanding is that this two strings don't always match, for example when changing the provider of the network while still using a SIM from the previous provider they can be different.

So I'm looking on how to get this codes in iOS, and I found that you can get a [CTCarrier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html) via [subscriberCellularProvider](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/subscriberCellularProvider). And from there you can get the [MCC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCarrier/mobileCountryCode) and [MNC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCarrier/mobileNetworkCode). But are these MCC and MCN strings from the **SIM operator** or from the **network operator**? And, is there any way of getting both things in iOS?